# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property [ 'src'] of undefined

Tags: javascript

// Add Images
    var aspect_ratio = '';
    var itemImagesHtml = '';
    itemImagesHtml += ' 0) {
        aspect_ratio = images[0]['width'] / images[0]['height'];
        itemImagesHtml += 1 / aspect_ratio * 100;
    } else {
        itemImagesHtml += 100;
    }
    itemImagesHtml += '%;">';
    itemImagesHtml += '';
    itemImagesHtml += '';
    itemImagesHtml += '';

```
var image_size = bcSfFilterConfig.custom.max_height + 'x' + bcSfFilterConfig.custom.max_height;
var max_width = images.length > 0 ? bcSfFilterConfig.custom.max_height * aspect_ratio : 0;
itemImagesHtml += '<noscript><img class="grid-view-item__image" src="' + this.getFeaturedImage(images, image_size + '@2x') + '" alt="{{itemTitle}}" style="max-width: ' + max_width + 'px;"></noscript>';
itemHtml = itemHtml.replace(/{{itemImages}}/g, itemImagesHtml);
```

Comment: please share the contents of `images` and share a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: please show detail code of image

Comment: Edited Please check it once again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `images` it is an array, and the second item in this array is not defined: `images[1]['src']`. Just ensure that you have the second item in this array

Comment: Yes i have actually same code is  working fine on other page

Answer (score 0):

Here, images[1] seems to be undefined. Most likely you are trying to access index 1 of images array, which doesn't exist.